# Pong game, detect if ball is out-of-bounds

Tags: haskell, pong, frp, kubernetes-helm

I'm writing a pong game, I need some help with the game logic. My problem is that is that I got trouble when detecting if the ball is out of the map or not, this causes that the ball just gets out-of-bounds and no score is counted. Currently it works like this:

```
stepScore :: State -> State
stepScore s
  | s^.ball.pos.x <= 15 = resetGame $ score.right +~ 1 $ s
  | s^.ball.pos.x >= 585 = resetGame $ score.left +~ 1 $ s
  | otherwise = s
```

The reason for the constants is that the game dimensions is 600x400 and the ball is 15 pixels wide and the position is in its core. resetGame works as such:

```
resetGame :: State -> State
resetGame s = ball.pos.y .~ 200 $ ball.pos.x .~ 300 $ state .~ Pause $ s
```

But somehow this doesn't work for some reason. The ball still gets out of the map and the game is basically broken.

So, my question is as follows; how can I write this so it works, basically, so the game resets and score is given to each player as intended when the ball is out-of-bounds? Full source code is here http://lpaste.net/91745, where the above code is defined at line 107 to 114, and used at line 118.

I would appreciate help, thanks.

EDIT: I tried different constants in stepScore, and stepScore IS the problem, it doesn't work for some reason. :(

Comment: I haven't used FRP that much, but it looks like you're forgetting to check your y-bounds as well in `stepScore`.  Is the ball exiting the playing field via the top or bottom edges?

Comment: @bheklilr Only via the left and right side, the top and bottom edges are collision checked and the balls direction is changed according to it.

Answer (score 1):

Code blidness... I forgot to put stepScore in the 'Play'-state.